# Forming XML from Json String Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, json, xml, xamarin.android

I am developing in Xamarin.Android. Trying to download xml from url as below and converting it to list of objects. But I am not able to form xml.

```
  WebClient client = new WebClient();
                //client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", " en-US");
                //client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/xml");
                //client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)");
                string downloadString = client.DownloadString(url);
                XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(downloadString);

                //XmlDocument doc = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(downloadString);
```

In above code different things are happening:

1. If I add headers, then no exception was thrown while parsing, but if I comment it, then while parsing I am getting exception as

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

2. After including Headers, I tried to convert it to valid xml by deserializing the json string, then below compile error was shown

> Error 2   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert' does not contain a definition
>   for 'DeserializeXmlNode'

I have added required namespaces.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

It is not PCL project and its not using any specific profile also. Please someone help me.

I could form xml by simply doing this:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(downloadString);
```

But after that I am not able to form list of object from xml.

```
var query = from data in doc.Root.Elements("Customer")
                            select new Customer
                            {
                                City = (string)data.Element("Address").Value,
                                CompanyName = (string)data.Element("Name").Value,
                                ID = Convert.ToInt32(data.Element("ID").Value),
                                WebsiteAddress = (string)data.Element("Website").Value
                            };

                var list = query.ToList();
```

Even though I have valid xml with 20 datas above query always returns 0 count.

Json:

> [{"ID":1,"Name":"Tata Consultancy
>   Services","Website":"www.tcs.com","Address":"Chennai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/tcs.png"},{"ID":2,"Name":"Tech
>   Mahindra","Website":"www.techmahindra.com","Address":"Mumbai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/tmah.png"},{"ID":3,"Name":"Accenture
>   Services Pvt.
>   Ltd","Website":"www.accenture.com","Address":"Mumbai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/accenture.png"},{"ID":4,"Name":"American
>   Express
>   (India)","Website":"www.americanexpress.com","Address":"Mumbai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/amex.png"},{"ID":5,"Name":"California
>   Software Co.
>   Ltd","Website":"www.calsoftgroup.com","Address":"Chennai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/calsoft.png"},{"ID":6,"Name":"Datamatics
>   Ltd","Website":"www.datamatics.com","Address":"Mumbai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/datamat.png"},{"ID":7,"Name":"Canon
>   India Pvt Ltd","Website":"www.canon-asia.com","Address":"New
>   Delhi","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/canon.png"},{"ID":8,"Name":"Symantec
>   Ltd","Website":"www.symsntec.com","Address":"Mumbai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/syman.png"},{"ID":9,"Name":"Cisco
>   Systems (India) Pvt. Ltd","Website":"www.cisco.com","Address":"New
>   Delhi","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/cisco.png"},{"ID":10,"Name":"Elgi
>   Software
>   Ltd","Website":"www.lg.com/india","Address":"Mumbai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/lg.png"},{"ID":11,"Name":"FLSmidth
>   Private
>   Limited","Website":"www.flsmidth.com","Address":"Chennai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/fls.png"},{"ID":12,"Name":"Genesis
>   Infotech Solutions Pvt.
>   Ltd","Website":"www.genesisintl.com","Address":"Chennai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/"},{"ID":13,"Name":"Godrej
>   Infotech
>   Ltd","Website":"www.godrej.com","Address":"Mumbai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/godrej.png"},{"ID":14,"Name":"Hamilton
>   Research & Technology Pvt.
>   Ltd","Website":"www.hamiltonresearch.com","Address":"Calcutta","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/"},{"ID":15,"Name":"HCL
>   Technologies
>   Ltd","Website":"","Address":"","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/hcl.png"},{"ID":16,"Name":"Hexaware
>   Technologies
>   Limited","Website":"www.hexaware.com","Address":"Mumbai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/hex.png"},{"ID":17,"Name":"HTC
>   Software Development
>   Centre","Website":"","Address":"chennai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/htc.png"},{"ID":18,"Name":"Huawei
>   Technologies India Pvt
>   Ltd","Website":"","Address":"Bangalore","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/huawei.png"},{"ID":19,"Name":"ICICI
>   Infotech Services
>   Ltd","Website":"","Address":"Mumbai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/"},{"ID":20,"Name":"Infosys
>   Technologies
>   Ltd","Website":"www.infy.com","Address":"Bangalore","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/"},{"ID":21,"Name":"GE
>   Capital Services
>   India","Website":"www.ge.com","Address":"Gurgaon","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/"},{"ID":22,"Name":"Godrej
>   Infotech
>   Ltd","Website":"www.godrej.com","Address":"Mumbai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/"},{"ID":23,"Name":"Kirloskar
>   Computer Services
>   Ltd","Website":"www.kcsl.com","Address":"Bangalore","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/"},{"ID":24,"Name":"Larsen
>   & Toubro Infotech
>   Limite","Website":"www.lntinfotech.com","Address":"Mumbai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/"},{"ID":25,"Name":"Motorola
>   India Electronics Private
>   Ltd","Website":"","Address":"Bangalore","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/"},{"ID":26,"Name":"Newgen
>   Software Technologies Ltd","Website":"","Address":"New
>   Delhi","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/"},{"ID":27,"Name":"NIIT
>   Ltd","Website":"www.niit.com","Address":"New
>   Delhi","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/niit.png"},{"ID":28,"Name":"Novell
>   Software Development (I)
>   Ltd","Website":"www.novell.com","Address":"Bangalore","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/novell.png"},{"ID":29,"Name":"Oracle
>   Solution Services (India) Pvt
>   Ltd","Website":"www.oracle.com","Address":"Bangalore","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/"},{"ID":30,"Name":"Ramco
>   Systems
>   Ltd","Website":"www.ramco.com","Address":"Chennai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/"},{"ID":31,"Name":"Sterling
>   Infotech
>   Limited","Website":"www.sterlingcarnegie.com","Address":"Chennai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/"},{"ID":32,"Name":"SRM
>   Technologies
>   Limited","Website":"www.srmsoft.com","Address":"chennai","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/srm.jpg"},{"ID":33,"Name":"SAP
>   India Pvt.
>   Ltd","Website":"www.sap.com/india","Address":"Bangalore","ImagePath":"http://test/lab/logos/sap.png"}]

Comment: How does your `json` look like?

Comment: It would help if you include both `Json` ,`Xml'  and the conversion code.

Comment: Post your full json pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a class like this below.

```
[Serializable]
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

Then you should be able to serialize/deserialize it the way you want.

```
    // You are getting the json from the web client. I am just using hard coded json to demonstrate.
    var json = @"[{""ID"":1,""Name"":""Tata Consultancy Services"",""Website"":""www.tcs.com"",""Address"":""Chennai"",""ImagePath"":""http://test/lab/logos/tcs.png""},{""ID"":2,""Name"":""Tech Mahindra"",""Website"":""www.techmahindra.com"",""Address"":""Mumbai"",""ImagePath"":""http://test/lab/logos/tmah.png""},{""ID"":3,""Name"":""Accenture Services Pvt. Ltd"",""Website"":""www.accenture.com"",""Address"":""Mumbai"",""ImagePath"":""http://test/lab/logos/accenture.png""},{""ID"":4,""Name"":""American Express (India)"",""Website"":""www.americanexpress.com"",""Address"":""Mumbai"",""ImagePath"":""http://test/lab/logos/amex.png""}]";

    //this will give you a list of customers.
    var customers = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(json);

    //To convert the list of customers to xml, do this.
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(customers.GetType());

    using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, customers);
        var xml = textWriter.ToString(); // xml variable should have what you are looking for.
    }
```

You can get a list of customers from "customers" variable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am getting valid xml in xml variable, but not able to convert to list of Customer.XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

                    var query = (from data in xDoc.Descendants("Customer")
                                select new Customer
                                {
                                    
                                }).ToList();

Comment: I already have a class decorated with XmlElement like this, [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }, in that Serializable was missed, you pointed out, now no exception, still not able to form list of customer object

Comment: Why do you need that Linq query? You already have a list of customers in `var customers = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(json);`

Comment: But values are null in that, hence trying to get it from xml

Comment: What values are "null"? If values are "null" in that, what you will be getting from xml will be null too. It doesn't make much sense to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, actually I am getting 33 items in customers list, but item values like name, address are null, but in xml I am able to see valid data

Comment: Under which IDs are you getting "null". Have a look at attached image to the answer.

Comment: I decorated Customer class properties with custom name attribute and was using different name in the variable, hence it was not binding, now working:) BTW, I dnt see any image attached in the answer.